# IValueResolver.Resolve not called on mapping AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to map IQueryable data in AutoMapper.

```
namespace Soure
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Department dept { get; set; }

        public Employee()
        {
            this.Id = 1;
            this.Name = "Test  Name";
            this.dept = new Department();
        }
    }

    public class Department
    {
        public int DeptId { get; set; }
        public string DeptName { get; set; }

        public Department()
        {
            DeptId = 2;
            DeptName = "Test Dept";
        }
    }
}

namespace destination
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Department dept { get; set; }

    }

    public class Department
    {
        public int DeptId { get; set; }
        public string DeptName { get; set; }
    }
}



var empList = new List<Soure.Employee>() { new Soure.Employee(), new Soure.Employee() }.AsQueryable();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Soure.Employee, destination.Employee>();

            Mapper.CreateMap<Soure.Department, destination.Department>().ForMember(d => d.DeptId, s => s.MapFrom(sou => 7));
            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

var mappedEmp = empList.Project().To<destination.Employee>();
```

I want to call ResolutionResult IValueResolver.Resolve(ResolutionResult source)
method on mapping .
But it doesn't get called.

When i use Map(sourceObject) 
this Mapper call ResolutionResult IValueResolver.Resolve(ResolutionResult source)

As i am having Queryable to Map so i can't use Map(sourceObject) .

Or is there any alternative method to  ResolutionResult IValueResolver.Resolve(ResolutionResult source) which works for AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions

Answer (score 0):

Value Resolvers [aren't supported for queryable extensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions#supported-mapping-options). LINQ providers can't interpret any random bit of code, it has to be interpretable by EF/NHibernate etc. AutoMapper merely passes an expression tree to a LINQ provider.

Your example uses MapFrom instead of ResolveUsing, so I can't tell if what you're trying to do is actually possible. Also, your example uses AsQueryable(), which is deceptive - lots of things are possible with the in-memory queryables that aren't possible with DB-based query providers.

Comment: I had try with ResolveUsing as it need IValueResolver which is not supported to Queryable thats why i am trying to achieve same thing with MapFrom.  How to achieve same functionality with MapFrom ? or any other way to achieve same functionality.

Comment: Achieve what exactly? The code you show in your example works just fine in LINQ.

Comment: Yes the above code works fine. But i want to give func instead of 7. And want result of func.

Comment: i am having 1 query as i just asked another question so i had blocked for next 1.5 hour but i want it immediately. It is related to linq. can you help me

Comment: Can you update your code to show the actual problem you're having?